# "Cannot add foreign key constraint". SQLfiddle

Tags: sqlfiddle

Por más que lo miro o lo mire el profesor nadie encuentra la solución. Ayuda.

> Error: Cannot add foreign key constraint

```
CREATE TABLE clase (
  clase char(20),
  tiempo_de_prestamo integer(2)

);

CREATE TABLE usuario (
  secuencia char(5),
  nombre char(10),
  direccion char(20),
  sexo char(1),
  fecha_ingreso date not null

);

CREATE TABLE libro (
  codigo integer(5),
  autor char(10),
  titulo char(20),
  editor char(15),
  indice integer,
  clase char(20),
  prestado char(5) DEFAULT '1',
  CONSTRAINT pk2 PRIMARY KEY(codigo),
  CONSTRAINT fk3 FOREIGN KEY(clase) REFERENCES clase(clase) 

);

CREATE TABLE prestamo (
  codigo integer(5),
  secuencia char(5),
  fecha_inicio date,
  CONSTRAINT pk8 PRIMARY KEY(codigo),
  CONSTRAINT fk4 FOREIGN KEY(codigo) REFERENCES libro(codigo),
  CONSTRAINT fk5 FOREIGN KEY(secuencia) REFERENCES usuario(secuencia)

);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una de las condiciones que se tienen que dar para que una clave pueda ser **foranea** es que esta sea **clave primaria** de su tabla. Por eso no se te está permitiendo realizarla.

Este sería el código que te permitiría hacer lo que pretendes:

```
CREATE TABLE clase (
  clase char(20),
  tiempo_de_prestamo integer(2),
  CONSTRAINT pkclase PRIMARY KEY(clase)
);

CREATE TABLE usuario (
  secuencia char(5),
  nombre char(10),
  direccion char(20),
  sexo char(1),
  fecha_ingreso date not null,
  CONSTRAINT pkusuario PRIMARY KEY(secuencia)
);

CREATE TABLE libro (
  codigo integer(5),
  autor char(10),
  titulo char(20),
  editor char(15),
  indice integer,
  clase char(20),
  prestado char(5) DEFAULT '1',
  CONSTRAINT pk2 PRIMARY KEY(codigo),
  CONSTRAINT fk3 FOREIGN KEY(clase) REFERENCES clase(clase) 
);

CREATE TABLE prestamo (
  codigo integer(5),
  secuencia char(5),
  fecha_inicio date,
  CONSTRAINT pk8 PRIMARY KEY(codigo),
  CONSTRAINT fk4 FOREIGN KEY(codigo) REFERENCES libro(codigo),
  CONSTRAINT fk5 FOREIGN KEY(secuencia) REFERENCES usuario(secuencia)
);
```