# Cannot add foreign key constraint. SQL

Tags: sql, sqlfiddle

Muy buenas, tengo un problema a la hora de realizar este ejercicio de clase y he llegado a un punto muerto. Se nos presenta la siguiente base de datos, y se deben realizar las relaciones presentadas en el código adjuntado, pero por mucho que cambie las propiedades de los campos o la posición de las tablas en las líneas de código, sigue dando el error "Cannot add foreign key constraint". Soy principante en SQL, y agradecería ayuda para resolver este error. ¡Gracias!

```
CREATE TABLE preinscripcion (
    dni          char(9),
    codigo       integer(10),
    orden        char(10),
    admitido     char(2),
CONSTRAINT pk0 PRIMARY KEY(dni,codigo)

);

CREATE TABLE alumno  (
    dni          char(9),
    nombre       char(10),
    nota         integer(2),
    opcion       char(1),
CONSTRAINT pk0 PRIMARY KEY(dni),
CONSTRAINT fk0 FOREIGN KEY(dni) REFERENCES preinscripcion(dni)

);


CREATE TABLE estudio  (

    codigo       integer(10),
    nombre       char(10),
    nota_corte   char(2),
CONSTRAINT pk1 PRIMARY KEY(codigo),
CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY(codigo) REFERENCES preinscripcion(codigo)


);


SELECT 
    nota_corte

FROM
    estudio
WHERE
    nota_corte >5

;

SELECT
    opcion
FROM
    alumno
WHERE
    opcion = "A,B,C,D"
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? ["Cannot add foreign key constraint". SQLfiddle](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328076/cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-sqlfiddle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si haces una `primary key` de dos campos deberías hacer la `foreing key` en consonancia, además creo que necesitas establecer los mismos campos como clave primaria en esas tablas (o crear un campo autonumérico y establecerlo como clave primaria):

```
CREATE TABLE preinscripcion (
    dni          char(9),
    codigo       integer(10),
    orden        char(10),
    admitido     char(2),
    CONSTRAINT pk0 PRIMARY KEY(dni,codigo)
);

CREATE TABLE alumno  (
    dni          char(9),
    codigo       integer(10),
    nombre       char(10),
    nota         integer(2),
    opcion       char(1),
    CONSTRAINT pk0 PRIMARY KEY(dni,codigo),
    CONSTRAINT fk0 FOREIGN KEY(dni,codigo) REFERENCES preinscripcion(dni,codigo)
);

CREATE TABLE estudio  (
    dni          char(9),
    codigo       integer(10),
    nombre       char(10),
    nota_corte   char(2),
    CONSTRAINT pk1 PRIMARY KEY(dni,codigo),
    CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY(dni,codigo) REFERENCES preinscripcion(dni,codigo)
);
```